# Specific column searching in entire schema to find does such column even exists or not

Tags: sql-server

How to Search a Specific column in entire schema of my database in SQL server 2005, that to which table the mentioned column belongs, or even exists or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view for the database to see if the column exists and which table it belongs to, have a look at the following which describes the columns in the view:

[Information Schema - Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The query is `Select * from information_schema.columns where column_name like '%ColumnName%'`

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample query where you're specifying the column name as '`AddressId`' and schema name as `person`.

[source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/)

Change column name and schema name as per your requirements

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%AddressId%' AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)='Person'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Result

[image]